# Functions versus mapping in a contract

Tags: erc-20

I am new to ethereum. I read about ERC20 standard. For example there is a `balanceOf()` function that is required to be implemented. But in some contracts that claim to be ERC20 compliant, instead of a function, a mapping is used:

```
mapping (address => uint256) public balanceOf;
```

And then it is used in the following way, for example:

```
balanceOf[msg.sender] = initialSupply;
```

My question is, is the above way conforms to ERC20, or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By including the `public` keyword on the mapping, the solidity compiler automatically creates a `constant` getter function which can be called as `token.balanceOf(address)`.

If you clone the ConsenSys token implementation, run `truffle compile`, and then open `./build/contracts/StandardToken.json`, you'll see this in the [ABI](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/abi-spec.html):

```
 {
  "constant": true,
  "inputs": [
    {
      "name": "_owner",
      "type": "address"
    }
  ],
  "name": "balanceOf",
  "outputs": [
    {
      "name": "balance",
      "type": "uint256"
    }
```